# Override Cosmos database used with Web Application Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a `CosmosClient` which is registered as a singleton, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CosmosClient>(serviceProvider =>
{
    var client = new CosmosClient(
        accountEndpoint: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Cosmos:Uri"),
        tokenCredential: new DefaultAzureCredential()
    );

    return client;
});
```

As I understand it, the best practice is to register the client and then create a new instance of the database object every time it is used, as such:

```
var database = _client.GetDatabase("Cocktails");
var container = database.GetContainer("Recipes");

var cocktail = new CocktailModel(
    // ...properties goes here
);

await container .CreateItemAsync(
    item: cocktail,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

I am aware of the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists()` method, but I would prefer not to use that in the production code.

What I would like to do, is to use a different database, for my integration tests, where I used the [Web Application Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Here is an example:

```
[Fact]
public void ListCocktails()
{
    var client = _factory.CreateClient();

    var response = client.GetAsync("/cocktails").Result;

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var cocktails = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CocktailResponse>>(content);

    Assert.NotNull(cocktails);
    Assert.NotEmpty(cocktails);
}
```

For a get request this is a fine test. But for testing write and delete, I would like to create a new database and delete it once the test is complete. With WAF I can replace various services, but I would like to replace the `Database` object (or actually it's initialization), so that I can use `CreateIfNotExists` for tests and `GetDatabase` for production.

The only way I can think of, is to create a service, which provides the database (e.g. `DatabaseFactory`) and replace that in the tests. But is this really the best way to do it? I feel like this should be a solved problem...

Comment: Creating a factory to provide the database was the only way I could find when I did this exact thing for a repository of my own. If there's a better way then I'd also like to know about it: https://github.com/martincostello/alexa-london-travel-site/blob/main/tests/LondonTravel.Site.Tests/Integration/InMemoryDocumentStore.cs

Comment: You can reuse the database that's returned from `GetDatabase`. It does hardly anything of importance in the background; Mostly just building up the url to which your requests get send. Same goes for the container.